# How can i pass a class variable to a view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have something like the following code :

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller {
  public $data; 

public function step1()
{
    $this->load->model('modelA');
    $modelT = new functionInsideModel();
    $data['1'] = $modelT -> F1();
    $data['2'] = $modelT -> F2();
    $data['3'] = $modelT -> F3();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('step1',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
public function step2()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $this->data['step1Check'] = true;
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('step2');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }


}
```

}

After the compilation of the form in step1 the customer goes on the step2. I need to implement a class varible $data['step1'], so if this variable is true that's meaning that the form in step1 is already completed and the step1 view will be different.

So, the customer in step2 wants to click on step1 to see if the insered informations are ok, since the customer is already in step2 the $data['step1'] is true and the step1 view will be different.

$data variable is a class variable, so it is "visible" in step1() function of the controller, but i cannot use it in the step1 view.

How can i resolve this issue  ?

Comment: You could pass variable as second param in $this->load->view() function. WangDong

Comment: The variable is already passed as second param ($data). In the view I can see all the $data variables initialed in the step1 function but I have the following error when I try to use the $data['step1Check'] ($step1Check in the view) :Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: step1Check

Comment: If you load step 1 then you load step 2 and then you load step 1 again the $data variable is re-initiated everytime so $data is empty at every request. What you need is session variables so that when you pass to step 2 you save that step 1 is completed and in step 1 check the session to see if it was completed

Comment: Yes, I understood...I'm so stupid....

Comment: Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller {
  public $data; 

public function step1()
{
    $this->data['step1Check'] = (isset($_SESSION['step1Check']) && $_SESSION['step1Check']);
    $this->load->model('modelA');
    $modelT = new functionInsideModel();
    $data['1'] = $modelT -> F1();
    $data['2'] = $modelT -> F2();
    $data['3'] = $modelT -> F3();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('step1',$this->data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
public function step2()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $_SESSION['step1Check'] = true;
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('step2');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }


}
}
```

This way you save it in a session and you have it on the next load of step 1 and this should not give you any warnings.
Also you need to initiate the session driver in config of codeiginiter.

Then to use in your view just use `$step1Check`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you instantiate your `$data` as an object or array.

After that, you will use the second parameter of the function `view` to pass your data array to the view template.

```php
$data = array(
    'title' => 'My Title',
    'heading' => 'My Heading',
    'message' => 'My Message'
);

$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('step2', $data);
$this->load->view('footer', $data);
```

And in your view, you can access your data in your array/object using this command inside the view php file, without `$data` in front of it:

```php
  // $data['title']
  echo $title;

  // $data['heading']
  echo $heading;

  // $data['message']
  echo $message;
```

Comment: The issue is that I'm trying to use a variable initated in the step2() function in the step1 function, but since $data variable is a class variable that should have to be visibile in the step1 function.